# Is $\ln(\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - x)$ an odd function?

Tags: graphing-functions, even-and-odd-functions

$f(x)$ is an odd function if $f(-x) = -f(x)$.

If $f(x) = \ln(\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - x)$, one can observe graphically that $f(-x) = -f(x)$.

[image]

Hence, $f(x)$ must be an odd function. However, WolframAlpha gives the following result:

[image]

Is WolframAlpha wrong, or have I made an error?

Comment: You're right, since  $(\sqrt{1+x^2}-x)(\sqrt{1+(-x)^2}-(-x))=1$.

Comment: It is worth noting that entering this into WolframAlpha gives $0$:  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FullSimplify%5BLog%5BSqrt%5B%28-x%29%5E2+%2B+1%5D+-+%28-x%29%5D+%2B+Log%5BSqrt%5Bx%5E2+%2B+1%5D+-+x%5D%2C+++Element%5Bx%2C+Reals%5D%5D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, indeed as noticed, we have that

$$f(x)+f(-x)=\ln(\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - x) +\ln(\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + x)=\ln(x^2+1-x^2)=\ln 1=0 $$

and therefore

$$f(x)+f(-x)=0 \iff f(x)=-f(-x)$$

Comment: This argument is correct for functions of a real variable, but it's important to point out some care is needed for complex variables, since $\ln z^{-1} = -\ln z$ holds generally away from the cut whereas $\ln (zw) = \ln z + \ln w$ does not and presumably the cuts are what's tripping Wolfram Alpha up.

Comment: @KBDave Thanks to have pointed out that.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that it is odd. To see why, rationalize the argument of $\ln$ by multiplying and dividing by $\displaystyle \sqrt{x^2+1} - x$.

As for posing the question directly to WolframAlpha, it's hard to tell what it is doing or why it might be returning the wrong information like it is since their code base is not open source. My best guess is it is somehow invoking the complex logarithm which can muck stuff up. WolframAlpha (and Mathematica more generally) is not great at very specific things, I guess you found one such thing.

Comment: WolframAlpha gives the alternate form $-\sinh^{-1}(x)$ and will recognize *that* as an odd function, but not this. Very strange.

Comment: TBH, I doubt that we'd be able to tell what WolframAlpha is doing here even if we had access to the source code.